# Heteroskedasticity in linear probability models

Tags: variance, least-squares, heteroscedasticity

I have a class on linear probability models. 
We want to estimate a model $y=\beta x$ where both $y$ and $x$ can be either $0$ or $1$, so that the conditional expectation function can be expressed in terms of probabilities:
$$
\mathbb{E}(y|x)=\Pr(y=1|x)=\beta x
$$

In the slides, it is said that we always need to use robust standard errors in the context of linear probability models because the conditional variance of the errors will always depend on the $x$'s.

However, I don't understand the proof that my teacher included. He writed
$$
\begin{aligned} \operatorname{Var}(\varepsilon | x) &=\operatorname{Var}(y | x) \\ &=E\left(y^{2} | x\right)-(E(y | x))^{2} \\ &=\operatorname{Pr}(y=1 | x)(1-\operatorname{Pr}(y=1 | x)) \\ &=x^{\prime} \beta\left(1-x^{\prime} \beta\right) \end{aligned}
$$

The two parts I'm not sure are

- $\operatorname{Var}(\varepsilon | x) =\operatorname{Var}(y | x)$,
- and $E\left(y^{2} | x\right)-(E(y | x))^{2}=\operatorname{Pr}(y=1 | x)(1-\operatorname{Pr}(y=1 | x))$

Could somebody explain me those computations?

Thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: You apparently make some implicit assumptions, of which the most striking is that $y$ is almost certainly equal to $0$ or $1.$  This must be one of the conditions required for the "always" to be true in your initial paragraph.  What other assumptions are you making that you did not explicitly state?

Comment: Yes sorry, in this example $y$ is either $0$ or $1$. I will add this in the question.