# Connection between standard error of OLS and Logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, standard-error

I know that for OLS: $y=X\beta+\epsilon$ with $\epsilon\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, we have $var(\widehat{\beta}|X)=\sigma^2(X^TX)^{-1}$. 
For logistic: $y^*=X\beta+\mu$, where $\mu\sim logit(0,1)$, and what we observe is y the indicator function, the variance of $\beta$ converges to $(X^TWX)^{-1}$, where $W$ is diagonal with entries $p(x_i)(1-p(x_i))$.

The two formulae seem so similar to me, not just the $X^TX$ bit but also $p(1-p)$ is the variance of the binary $y$. It's clear to me in OLS, variance of $\beta$ increases as variance of error increases. For logistic, can I understand it as: the variance of $y$ goes into $X\beta$ with variance of $\mu$ fixed, so it kind of goes to $\mu$ inversely with $X\beta$ fixed? In particular, I am wondering if my $X$ and underlying $\beta$ are the same, with the same variance in $\epsilon$ and $\mu$, would my standard errors be pretty much the same/similar?

Comment: *"For logistic: $y^*=X\beta+\mu$, where $\mu\sim logit(0,1)$"* This isn't very clear (and possibly incorrect).

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus do you mind explaining what isn't clear? I thought that's the latent model representation, this is the wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression#:~:text=As%20a%20latent%2Dvariable%20model,-The%20logistic%20model&text=i.e.%20the%20latent%20variable%20can,to%20a%20standard%20logistic%20distribution.

Comment: The latent variable is a logistic distributed variable. The expression $\mu \sim logit(0,1)$ doesn't seem a lot like that. Sidenote: The latent variable model is not the most general expression of a logistic regression model. The logistic binomial regression model can have different motivations than this specific latent variable model. (I am personally [not a fan](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/622222/) and unaware of cases that make sense). I hadn't expected that you were referring to the latent variable model (as the $logit(0,1)$ was confusing and made it difficult to interpret).

Comment: The logistic regression setup is incorrect, [see here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/124847) for comparison; that might explain the confusion. Also, your $p(1-p)$ variance term stems from [linear probability models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/405904).

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus thanks for the explanation! so I should've wrote logistic(0,1) instead right?

Comment: @Durden thanks for you comment! For the p in p(1-p), I meant to say p=e^.../(1+e^...), which I think is the probability that y*>0 and is the same as the p in the diagonal entries of W. Please correct me if I'm wrong, thanks!